# can't show mapbox on post that posted before

Tags: javascript, browser, geometry, coordinates, geojson

[source problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5j2On.png)[console problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56qyU.png)first  of all sorry about my English i hope you will understand me.
I'm in the final step of my full stack course.
the last project is to build a site with API of Mapbox.
The problem is that when i try to show the map on post that posted, it's not finding the number of the coordinates.
it shows me a problem in the console, but if I'm posting a new post with a location it shows the sources the number of the coordinates.
i can't find the problem that cause that...

```
`mapboxgl.accessToken = mapToken;
const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map', // container ID
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v12', // style URL
    center: campground.geometry.coordinates, // starting position [lng, lat]
    zoom: 9, // starting zoom
    });

new mapboxgl.Marker()
    .setLngLat(JSON.parse(campground.geometry.coordinates))
    .addTo(map);`
```

**this is the mapShowPage**

```
`  <script>
const mapToken = '<%-process.env.MAPBOX_TOKEN%>';
const campground = <%- JSON.stringify(campground) %>
    
  </script>
<script src="/javascripts/showPageMap.js"></script>
```

`

**this is the show page file.**

I know where is the problem but i don't know how to try to fix it.
the problem is with the coordinates number in the post that exist

Comment: What error message in the console?  What is the value of `campground.geometry.coordinates`?  Are you sure it needs to be Json.parsed or is it already a JavaScript object?

Comment: i added a photo of the problem of the console

Comment: There are no coordinates in the campground.geometry.coordinates array.  Maybe you deleted them for privacy.  If it's just an array with numbers you should not use JSON.parse around campground.geometry.coordinates.  Check what is the value of campground.geometry.coordinates before the `new mapboxgl.Map` line to be sure it's what you expect.

Comment: lng_lat.js:163 Uncaught Error: `LngLatLike` argument must be specified as a LngLat instance, an object {lng: <lng>, lat: <lat>}, an object {lon: <lng>, lat: <lat>}, or an array of [<lng>, <lat>]
    at jl.convert (lng_lat.js:163:15)
    at Map.jumpTo (camera.js:1057:32)
    at new Map (map.js:597:18)
    at showPageMap.js:2:13

if I change the code to what you say it shows me this message on the console ,
the problem is when I try to open a new post with new coordinates number is work without problem in the console